# rdfproc took forever to parse a 8.33 MB file?

Tags: rdf, jena, redland

I'm trying to combine all my ttl files into one data dump, but when I try to do

```
rdfproc test_big parse vm_base.ttl turtle
```

It's taking forever, still waiting..., making me suspect it has stuck somewhere.

Is there a better alternative which can do this faster?
Other than I manually open all files in Protégé, which is what I have been doing, and find it time-consuming.

The file, if you need to test:
https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema/blob/master/example/sparql-generate/result/azure/v1.0.1/2019-03-07/vm_base.ttl

---

**Edit**
I did a test with `riot` merging 2 files, but why does it give duplicated `@prefix` declarations?

```
@prefix schema:  <https://schema.org/> .
@prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix cocoon:  <https://w3id.org/cocoon/v1.0.1#> .

<https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/v1.0.1/Device/150.203.213.249/lat=-35.271475/long=149.121434>
        <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  cocoon:Device ;
        rdfs:comment  "The computer used to conduct the tests, belongs to Australian National University College of Engineering & Computer Science."@en ;
        rdfs:label    "CECS-030929"@en .

_:b0    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  schema:Place .

_:b1    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  schema:GeoCoordinates ;
        schema:address    "Hanna Neumann Building #145, Science Road, Canberra ACT 2601" ;
        schema:latitude   "-35.271475" ;
        schema:longitude  "149.121434" .

_:b0    schema:geo  _:b1 .

<https://w3id.org/cocoon/data/v1.0.1/Device/150.203.213.249/lat=-35.271475/long=149.121434>
        cocoon:inPhisicalLocation  _:b0 ;
        cocoon:ipv4                "150.203.213.249" .
@prefix schema:  <https://schema.org/> .
@prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix cocoon:  <https://w3id.org/cocoon/v1.0.1#> .

<1-KB>  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  schema:TypeAndQuantityNode ;
        schema:amountOfThisGood  "1"^^xsd:interger ;
        schema:unitText          "KB" ;
        schema:unitCode          "2P" .
```

I tested with files

1. https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema/blob/master/example/sparql-generate/result/device.ttl
2. https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema/blob/master/example/sparql-generate/result/qos_property.ttl

Comment: what would be the purpose of just parsing it? Converting to N-Triples takes 3s with `rapper -i turtle -o ntriples vm_base.ttl > vm_base.nt` - you can't concatenate Turtle, for N-Triples you have to handle blank nodes. You can use Jena RIOT or RDF4J and load multiple files in-memory from CLI and then output it as whatever you need.

Comment: I want to merger multiple turtle files into one file (any serialization format).

Comment: as I said, then use Apache Jena RIOT or RDF4J - both provide CLI tools. For example, in Jena the most convenient way is to use `rdfcat -out Turtle file_1 file_2 ... file_n > merged_file.ttl`

Comment: `rdfcat` says " DEPRECATED: Please use 'riot' instead."

Comment: yeah, then use `riot`, where is the problem? `riot --output=Turtle file_1 file_2 ... file_n > merged_file.ttl`

Comment: just a minor comment, everything has to be loaded in-memory here, if you have too many too large files, you'll likely run out of memory. In that case, loading it into a triple store (Jena TDB, Virtuoso, Stardog, GraphDB, etc ...) can help

Comment: well, actually it looks like I was totally wrong and `riot` is handling each file separately because of it's underlying streaming mechanism. Let me double check how to proceed

Comment: `riot --formatted=Turtle device.ttl qos_property.ttl > test.ttl` will avoid trying to apply streaming for `Turtle` format. Try it